# addControls for a pieChart using nPlot() in rChart

Tags: rcharts

Is addControls() compatible with type=pieChart using nPlot()?
The pie chart disappears as soon as I try to add controls.

Im attempting the following:

```
Sp = c("a", "b", "c", "d") 
A = c(10, 4, 3, 0) 
B = c(3, 5, 22, 4) 
C = c(1, 0 ,10, 8)
df = data.frame(Sp, A, B, C)

p1 <- nPlot(x = "Sp", y ="A" ,
        color = 'Sp', data = df, type = 'pieChart')
p1$addControls('y', 'A', values=c('A','B','C'))
p1
```

It works perfectly if I use multiBarHorizontalChart instead.

Thank you!

Comment: Certain chart types in NVD3, which includes Pie Charts, use a very different data structure from the others. So `addControls` is not compatible with them.

Comment: Ramnath, Well, that's unfortunate, but thank you for the quick response.  (And thank you for rCharts!)

Comment: Actually, it is a bug, which I fixed. See my answer below. Thanks for bringing it up. Also note that you need to use `group` instead of `color` for the group controls to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, I realized that this is a bug in `rCharts`, which has been fixed on the `dev` branch. You can install it using `devtools::install_github('ramnathv/rCharts@dev')`.

So running the code below will produce [this chart with controls](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?8825574)

```
library(rCharts)
Sp = c("a", "b", "c", "d") 
A = c(10, 4, 3, 0) 
B = c(3, 5, 22, 4) 
C = c(1, 0 ,10, 8)
df = data.frame(Sp, A, B, C)

p1 <- nPlot(x = "Sp", y ="A" , data = df,
  group = 'Sp', type = 'pieChart'
)
p1$addControls('y', 'A', values=c('A','B','C'))
p1
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Works perfectly.  Thank you for the Group vs color note too.

Comment: Ramnath, After working perfectly for a week  devtools::install_github('ramnathv/rCharts@dev') no longer seems to work.  Is this something that has changed on your end?  Sorry to hassle you... I was just so thrilled to have something that worked!

Comment: `install_github` is a `devtools` function. What error message are you getting when you try `install_github('ramnathv/rCharts@dev')`? UPDATE: I just tested the entire code sequence and it is working perfectly.

Comment: I'm sure its probably something Im doing wrong, but Im not sure how to trouble shoot.  Here is the error:

Comment: Sorry, here it is:  `* installing *source* package 'rCharts' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'base64enc'
Error : unable to load R code in package 'rCharts'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rCharts'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rCharts'
* restoring previous '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rCharts'
Error: Command failed (1)`

Comment: Run `install.packages('base64enc')` before installing rCharts. I will added `base64enc` to Suggests, since it is required only if you want truly standalone charts that also work offline.

Comment: Now I just feel silly for not trying that before.  Works perfectly again!  Thanks!

Comment: Don't be. I have been bitten by dependency bugs many a time. It is the responsibility of the package author :)